# Why needn't the author to wrap text.isNotBlank() with remember?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the official Sample project [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#6).

1: I think I can wrap `text.isNotBlank()` with`remember`, so I think Code B is good, right?

BTW, I know the system will re-calculate when the `text` ( `val (text, setText) = remember { mutableStateOf("") }` ) is changed. So

2: In Code B,  `val (icon, setIcon) = remember { mutableStateOf(TodoIcon.Default)}` and  `val iconsVisible = remember {text.isNotBlank() }` will be re-launched when the text is changed (`val (text, setText) = remember { mutableStateOf("") }`) , right?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun TodoItemInput(onItemComplete: (TodoItem) -> Unit) {
   val (text, setText) = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   val (icon, setIcon) = remember { mutableStateOf(TodoIcon.Default)}
   val iconsVisible = text.isNotBlank()
   Column {
       Row( /* ... */ ) {
           /* ... */
       }
       if (iconsVisible) {
           AnimatedIconRow(icon, setIcon, Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp))
       } else {
           Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
       }
   }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun TodoItemInput(onItemComplete: (TodoItem) -> Unit) {
   val (text, setText) = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   val (icon, setIcon) = remember { mutableStateOf(TodoIcon.Default)}
   val iconsVisible = remember {text.isNotBlank() } //I add  remember 
   Column {
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `remember` as in Code B, `iconsVisible` will be calculated only once and the same value will be used across all recompositions and not get updates when `text` changes, which is not what we want here.

If you want to use `remember` here, you should pass `text` as a key to it, `remember(text) { text.isNotBlank() }`. But as this is not a time consuming calculation, you can just skip the `remember` block and use it as in Code A. The `.isNotBlank()` function will be invoked in every recomposition but that doesn't matter much here.

Comment: Thanks! In Code A, do you mean that `val (icon, setIcon) = remember { mutableStateOf(TodoIcon.Default)}` will not re-launched when `text` is changed?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: And  in Code A, do you mean that `val iconsVisible = text.isNotBlank()` will re-launched when `text` is changed?

Comment: `text` represents a `State`. The entire composable will be re-invoked when `text` changes. `text` and `icon` will be initialized to their cached values while `iconsVisible` will be calculated as `text.isNotBlank()`.